# What URL should I use when using the Teams conferencing API?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to use Teams' conference API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/create-apps-for-teams-meetings?tabs=json

But I don't know what to specify in the URL.
Ex) When using Get Partisipant API
GET {URL} / v1 / meetings / {meetingId} / partials / {participantId}? tenantId = {tenantId}

In this case, what should I specify in the URL?
If you know it, please let me know.
If you have any documents, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Source of `GetParticipant` is Microsoft Bot Framework SDK. Endpoint of APIs under Bot Framework SDK is its service URL (example- https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis). You will get the service URL in incoming request whenever user send a message to the bot, follow this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#base-uri) of documentation to learn more about it.

In order to use this Bot framework REST APIs you will also need `Access token`. This is how you can get it

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MICROSOFT-APP-ID&client_secret=MICROSOFT-APP-PASSWORD&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default
```

You can find additional information in this document - [Request access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#step-1-request-an-access-token-from-the-azure-ad-v2-account-login-service)

To use `GetParticipant` API you need a bot to be installed in the meeting(*use same App Id and Secret to get access token*). We have meeting bot [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-events/csharp) which you can try.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me.
I'll give it a try.